# Should a list or array of objects be represented as a lifeline in sequence diagram?

Tags: sequence-diagram

I have the following sequence diagram to add a student to a list of students.
the implementation could be like

```
List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
Students.Add(aStudent);
```

I drew the following sequence diagram for it:

[image]

In this diagram `Students` is actually the list of students mentioned in the code.

I would like to know is it a correct way to show a list of objects as a object lifeline? I mean as a conceptual and analysis approach and also at syntax.

For example maybe the `List<Student>` could be the object of a general class named  `Storage` which is responsible to store and retrieve a list of objects like a database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Description of **lifeline** from [UML 2.4.1 standard](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/):

> A Lifeline is shown using a symbol that consists of a rectangle forming its “head” followed by a vertical line (which may
>   be dashed) that represents the lifetime of the participant. Information identifying the lifeline is displayed inside the
>   rectangle in the following format:
>
> ```
> <lifelineident> ::= ([<connectable-element-name>[‘[‘ <selector> ‘]’]] [: <class_name>] [decomposition]) | ‘self’
> <selector> ::= <expression>
> <decomposition> ::= ‘ref’ <interactionident> [‘strict’]
> ```

So, you should rename `Students` to `Students : List<Student>` or just `:List<Student>`. The part after colon (`:`) represents a type (`<class_name>` from notation above).

There is no special syntax for representing lists.

**EDIT:** as for "Student Storage/Adapter"

If List does the job, just use it. It is object-oriented enough as it is. No need to introduce a pattern for the sake of introducing a pattern, and more than so for the sake of writing a busy-sounding class name to a diagram. [Keep it simple.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: I drew it in Visio, for example the class of Form1 is Form but it didn't show it, anyway thank you! but still I didn't get is it a right way to use a list or not! I mainly mean at conceptual analysis and not necessarily syntax

Comment: That is OK at conceptual level too. Your list is a valid participant of a process, and it doesn't really matter if it's a list or something else anyways - it a sequence diagram, not class diagram.

Comment: Could we say its actually a class like StudentAdapter or ... which is responsible to keep the list of students or save them in a database or ... So maybe its better to have a class for it where the storage is not specified and manipulation to the storage are shown? I modified my question to add that.